# PHP DOM Parser - get all nodes between two known XPaths

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, domparser

How to select all DOM nodes between 2 known XPaths?

```
Xpath1 = html/body/div[2]/p
Xpath2 = html/body/div[2]/p/a[3]
```

DOM Structure:

```
<html>
<body> 
<div id="id3">
    <p id="p3">
        text1 
        <a href="#">
            goal
        </a>
        text2 
        <a href="#">
            Crowdrise
        </a>.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($domain);

$x = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$el = $x->query("....??");
```

So, basically looking for a query method to select all nodes between the two XPaths.
I saw a couple of similar questions, however they seem to relate to XSLT cases.

Comment: What do you mean `between`? If you pick 2 branches on a tree, which branches are `between`? Also, XSLT uses XPath as it's expression language, so those answers may apply.

Comment: There are no branches in XPath. Everything is a node. If you have 20 nodes and pick 7 and 15, you want a method to select node 7-15 (incl)

Comment: XPath is a tree addressing language, and the concept of a tree is the concept of a branch. How would you order those nodes 1..20, exactly? Here's what I mean: if I take 'all the nodes in between', I'd have to know the path from one node to the other. Starting at the deepest node, I'd ascend one step (parent node), and look around to see if the other node is a sibling. But, you won't find a path that way between any two nodes in any tree without also recursing (descending into sibling nodes) if you have to.

Comment: In your example, there are no nodes between `Xpath1` and `Xpath2`. The latter is a direct child of the former. Or, if you include the start and the end, then the path *is* `Xpath1, Xpath2`.

Comment: What makes the question more confusing for me is that the HTML posted doesn't correspond to the xpath examples, i.e there is no `div[2]` and `a[3]` anywhere in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.
There is no general way of doing that because it depends on the position of the second element relatively to the first. I mean that if the second element is a descendant of the first or it's in another branch - those two are completely different.
so we need to make an assumption:

- Let's assume that the second element defined by the second path will always be a descendant of the first element defined the by first path.

Our goal will be to get all descendant elements (without text nodes) of the first element without the shared descendant of the second one.

To achieve that we need an expression:

```
el1 = All element 1 descendants.
el2 = All element 2 descendants including self. 
result = el1 [position() <= count( el1 ) - count( el2 )]
```

As you can see we are building a set of the first N elements until we reach the second element.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html>'
    . '         <body>'
    . '             <div>'
    . '                 <h1>shlomi</h1>'
    . '                 <p>'
    . '                     <span>goal1</span>'
    . '                     text1' 
    . '                     <a href="#">goal2</a>'
    . '                     text2'
    . '                     <a href="#"><span></span>Crowdrise</a>'
    . '                     .' 
    . '                 </p>'
    . '             </div>'
    . '         </body>'
    . '     </html>');

$x = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$path1 = "/html/body/div/p/descendant::*";               // all descendant elements without text
$path2 = "/html/body/div/p/a[2]/descendant-or-self::*";  // all descendant elements without text including self
$path3 = $path1."[position() <= count(".$path1.") - count(".$path2.")]"; 
$elList = $x->query($path3);

foreach ($elList as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeName." -> text: ".$node->textContent."<br />";
}
```

this will print:

```
span -> text: goal1
a    -> text: goal2
```

**Note** I'm using `*` to target only elements without text nodes - If you want all nodes replace it with `node()`.